# MS Excel query on conditional summing

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following table:
Red: 4
Green: 3
Red: 6

If i want to make excel skip rows and only sum the reds (so red sum is 10) - which formula can I use?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you're question correctly, you can use the SUMIF function. If the color names are in Column A, rows 1-3, and the values in Column B, rows 1-3, your formula might look like this: =SUMIF(A1:A3,"Red",B1:B3).